# How do I change the text of the x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following graph:

[image]

As you can see, the x-axis has the increments of 2000. The x-axis values are time, and I had to make changes to the time values to get them to work properly. An example of the x values (time list) is:

```
t_list = [13264,13273,13.279,13.301...]
```

I want to the x-axis to be in increments of 0.1, and change the values in the time list to be as follows:

```
t_list = [13.264,13.643,13.689,13.701...]
```

And I only want the x-axis to display the first decimal, but also include a "1:" with it (`1:13.1, 1:13.2,1:13.3,etc.`)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`locator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick-locators.html) to tell where to put the ticks, e.g. multiples of 100.
And a [`formatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html) to tell how to display the values:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 2))
ax.plot([13100, 22000], [1, 1])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(100))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'1:{x / 1000:.1f}')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90) # optionally rotate the ticks
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: custom tick formatter]

You can also combine minor and major ticks. Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 2))
ax.plot([13100, 22000], [1, 1])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1000))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'1:{x / 1000:.0f}')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(100))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'.{(x / 100) % 10:.0f}')

ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=12, length=12)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', labelsize=9)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: combining major and minor ticks]